# Error while including jar files in a batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, classpath

I was trying to compile my Java program with this batch file:

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin
set library=C:/lib/commons-io-1.2.jar;C:/lib/aspectjrt.jar;C:/lib/certjFIPS.jar;C:/lib/ci.jar;C:/lib/jsafeFIPS.jar;C:/lib/jaxb-api.jar;C:/lib/configservice-api.jar;C:/lib/configservice-impl.jar;C:/lib/dfc.jar;C:/lib/jaxb-impl.jar;C:/lib/log4j.jar;C:/lib/Logger.jar;;
cd C:\Projects\temp\code\project
javac -classpath C:\classes;%library%  -d C:\classes\temp\code\project\ *.java
```

But it throws the following error:

> Import statement from jar files doesn't exist

Comment: can you post the exception , that will be helpfull to debug, also please look at the exception carefully.

Comment: Seems like you are replacing the whole content of the %PATH% variable with only the path to your JDK, which isn't a good practice. You should append the new path instead (`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin`), or use the full path when calling javac.

Comment: @r0ast3d This is exception:<br/>DqlUtility.java:6: package com.documentum.com does not exist
import com.documentum.com.DfClientX;
                         ^
DqlUtility.java:7: package com.documentum.com does not exist
import com.documentum.com.IDfClientX;
                         ^
DqlUtility.java:8: package com.documentum.fc.client does not exist
import com.documentum.fc.client.DfQuery;DqlUtility.java:40: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IDfClientX
location: class com.dqlutility.DqlUtility
                        IDfClientX clientX = new DfClientX();

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your code that you are trying to compile, is this the first time that this has happenned?

Comment: @r0ast3d yes its actually first time i am running this code from batch file.I dont think there is problem with code because we have run it in eclipse , it runs fine .The problem is it just cant locate packages in jar files when run from a batch file

Comment: Did you check for case sensitivity in your class path?

Comment: @r0ast3d Can you posta sample batch file which references some external jar file.It would be a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows I've seen similar error solved using quotes around the classpath argument

`-classpath "C:\classes;%library%"`